# I'm trying to download a PDF from a website with a script. Keep on getting undefined properties can't read 'save' in chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, console, jspdf

I'm not really proficient at JS or coding in general. I found this script online that should help me download a protected pdf from a website. Everything works fine and the pdf autoscrolls until I get to the save function and that's when I get this error from the console

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'save') at generatePDF (<anonymous>:59:6) at <anonymous>:105:25`

it seems that the problem command is this one

`doc.save(pdfDocumentName);`

Here is the full code. I'm not sure what the issue is

```
let jspdf = document.createElement("script");
jspdf.onload = function () {
    let pdfDocumentName = "Document";
    let doc;

    function generatePDF (){
        let imgTags = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
        let checkURLString = "blob:https://drive.google.com/";
        let validImgTagCounter = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < imgTags.length; i++) {

            if (imgTags[i].src.substring(0, checkURLString.length) === checkURLString){
                validImgTagCounter = validImgTagCounter + 1;
                //console.log(imgTags[i].src);
                let img = imgTags[i];

                let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
                canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;
                //console.log("Width: " + img.naturalWidth + ", Height: " + img.naturalHeight);
                context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight);
                let imgDataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
               // console.log(imgDataURL);

                //let ratio;
                let orientation;
                if (img.naturalWidth > img.naturalHeight){
                    //console.log("Landscape");
                    orientation = "l";
                    //ratio = img.naturalWidth/img.naturalHeight
                }else {
                    //console.log("Portrait");
                    orientation = "p";
                    //ratio = img.naturalWidth/img.naturalHeight
                }

                let scalefactor = 1.335;
                let pageWidth = img.naturalWidth * scalefactor;
                let pageHeight = img.naturalHeight * scalefactor;
               //let imagexLeft = (pageWidth - img.naturalWidth)/2;
               //let imagexTop = (pageHeight - img.naturalHeight)/2;
                if (validImgTagCounter === 1){
                    doc = new jsPDF({
                        orientation: orientation,
                        unit: "px",
                        format: [pageWidth, pageHeight],
                    });
                    doc.addImage(imgDataURL, "PNG", 0, 0, img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight);
                }else{
                    doc.addPage([pageWidth, pageHeight] , orientation);
                    doc.addImage(imgDataURL, "PNG", 0, 0, img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight);
                }
            }
        }

        pdfDocumentName = pdfDocumentName + ".pdf";
    doc.save(pdfDocumentName);
    }


    let allElements = document.querySelectorAll("*");
    let chosenElement;
    let heightOfScrollableElement = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
        if ( allElements[i].scrollHeight>=allElements[i].clientHeight){
            if (heightOfScrollableElement < allElements[i].scrollHeight){
                //console.log(allElements[i]);
                //console.log(allElements[i].scrollHeight);
                heightOfScrollableElement = allElements[i].scrollHeight;
                chosenElement = allElements[i];
            }
        }
    }

    if (chosenElement.scrollHeight > chosenElement.clientHeight){
        console.log("Auto Scroll");

        let scrollDistance = Math.round(chosenElement.clientHeight/2);
        //console.log("scrollHeight: " + chosenElement.scrollHeight);
        //console.log("scrollDistance: " + scrollDistance);

        let loopCounter = 0;
        function myLoop(remainingHeightToScroll, scrollToLocation) {
            loopCounter = loopCounter+1;
            console.log(loopCounter);

            setTimeout(function() {
                if (remainingHeightToScroll === 0){
                    scrollToLocation = scrollDistance;
                    chosenElement.scrollTo(0, scrollToLocation);
                    remainingHeightToScroll = chosenElement.scrollHeight - scrollDistance;
                }else{
                    scrollToLocation = scrollToLocation + scrollDistance ;
                    chosenElement.scrollTo(0, scrollToLocation);
                    remainingHeightToScroll = remainingHeightToScroll - scrollDistance;
                }

                if (remainingHeightToScroll >= chosenElement.clientHeight){
                    myLoop(remainingHeightToScroll, scrollToLocation)
                }else{
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        generatePDF();
                    }, 1500)
                }

            }, 500)
        }
        myLoop(0, 0);

    }else{
        console.log("No Scroll");
        setTimeout(function() {
            generatePDF();
        }, 1500)
    }


};
jspdf.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.debug.js';
document.body.appendChild(jspdf);
```

I'd appreciate any and all help!

Comment: It appears that you're initialising the `doc` variable within an `if` statement. I don't see the need to have it there so I'd say remove the initialisation block from there and put it right above the `if (validImgTagCounter === 1)` statement. Then at the point where you call `doc.save(pdfDocumentName)` add a check to see if `doc` has a value.

Comment: @deltanboi, I moved the intialisation of the doc variable just on top of the if statement. I also added a check. Now the code doesn't throw any errors but I don't get any file to download. The browser scrolls through the document and I see this counter going in my console until it reaches the last page and I get no output. Not sure what the issue is now

Comment: could you maybe create a pen on codepen.io or some sort of playground I can use to help debug the code.

Comment: @Ochuko Thank you so much for taking the time to do this! Here is the pen: https://codepen.io/Musa-Khattak/pen/mdaMWKj

I haven't added anything in the HTML or CSS sections, wasn't sure what would've been appropriate

Comment: it would be helpful to have the HTML and CSS as well cos right now we just have JS code not working with anything. You can make sure to replace anything that you feel might be sensitive data.

Comment: @Ochuko I've simulated a PDF viewer now with the HTML and CSS. This is the kind of webpage I would be using this code on to download the PDF. Here is the pen: https://codepen.io/Musa-Khattak/pen/eYbEbqd

Comment: Having gone through the code I realise you're trying to target the `img` tags in the Adobe iframe that are rendering the PDF file. Unfortunately, you can't just access the content of an iframe the way you're trying to. The only way I know you can get content from an iframe is through the `contentWindow`, as seen here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_element_iframe

Unfortunately, this is not reliable as most sites implement CORS policies which block unauthorised access from external domains.

Comment: I tired using the example code to access the `img` tags in the iframe and it returned a CORS error as expected. 

Just to be clear, the reason why the code doesn't do anything is because `document.getElementsByTagName("img")` returns an empty array since there aren't any images that are not inside the iframe, and the `img` tags you want to access are inside the iframe which is guarded by a CORS policy.

Comment: @Ochuko That makes sense now. Thank you so much for helping me out here. Bit disappointing that the code won’t work but I’ve learnt a lot from this.

Comment: Glad I could help (in some way)!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this fragment is not executed:

```js
doc = new jsPDF({
  orientation: orientation,
  unit: "px",
  format: [pageWidth, pageHeight],
});
```

Make sure that:

- imgTags.length > 0
- imgTags[i].src.substring(0, checkURLString.length) === checkURLString
- validImgTagCounter > 0

In other cases, `doc` is equal to `undefined`. That is causing error.

You can also add protection, before executing save() function.

```js
if (validImgTagCounter > 0) {
  doc.save(pdfDocumentName);
}
```